# how to measure size of string inside the control in C#?

Tags: c#

inside the control how to measure the text string will cut or not.

I am using this code which returns me the value. but when the height and width of text are same as of control then also the cut happens. So how to find or any other API is there to find the text cut.

```
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
        testString,
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface("Verdana"),
        32,
        Brushes.Black);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Could you clarify? Are you just looking for a way to measure a string in WPF?

Comment: Win Forms or WPF I take it?

Comment: When want to measure a string, you should take a look at [the method named `MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx)  Or the slightly more accurate [`MeasureCharacterRanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Or [MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is closer to how controls actually draw text in WinForms).

Comment: Or call Measure on the formattedText, then look at the DesiredSize property (don't forget to also set the attached TextOptions.TextFormattingMode property as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

i m looking  to finding the string's pixel width and height in WPF.
That function i mention gives value but when the text size and control size is same then text cut happens. so how to know when text cut happens?

Comment: by using the  FormattedText, i am not able to get the string width and height if the string size is more then TextBox